# Usuário por Empresa - Asp.net Identity

Tags: asp.net-identity

Gostaria de uma ajuda com o *Identity* por favor. 
Aqui o cadastro de usuário é por Filial, fiz a customização do *ApplicationUser* colocando o campo *FilialID* e o campo na tabela *AspNetUsers*, tudo funcionando perfeito, porém agora na hora do login teria que ser verificado *username*, senha e filial pois tenho, por exemplo, usuário "eduardo" na filial "01" e usuário "eduardo" na filial "02". 
A Filial eu pego por parâmetro na *querystring*, e a tela de login continua apenas com os campos *UserName* e Password. Tem como fazer isso? Por onde eu começo? Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Você poderia colocar exemplos do seu código para podermos melhorar as respostas?

Answer (score 0):

O login precisa ser feito com usuários únicos. Isso em regra geral, mas especialmente se você estiver usando `Asp.net Identity`.

Não pode haver dois usuários '**Eduardo**'. Mesmo que estejam em filiais diferentes.

Os usuários deverão ser '**Eduardo1**' e '**eduardo.Souza**', por exemplo. Ou talvez usar o e-mail. Enfim, devem ser diferentes. **E isso é bom!** Imagine se ficasse como você queria, e em algum momento um dos **eduardos** mudasse para a filial onde o outro está! Você teria dois usuários na mesma filial, com o mesmo nome.

---

Com relação ao acesso diferenciado pela filial, tudo certo. O seu sistema sabe a qual filial cada usuário pertence, e pode usar isso para controlar o acesso/exibir as opções adequadas.

Answer (score 0):

Em relação ao modelo, agora está tudo bem, mas e se por ventura necessite de mudanças, tipo, agora um usuário controla duas filiais!? você poderá ter problemas quanto a isso. O que você pode fazer é manter a tabela AspNetUsers como está e criar uma Tabela Filiais, com o relacionamento apontando para a de usuários.

```
//Tabela AspNetUser
Id
Username
Email
EmailConfirmed
...

//Tabela Filiais
FilialID
UsuarioAspNetID
FilialNome
...
```